# Express Knowledge base in CNF and resolution in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a knowledge base as CNF and i'd like to use prolog to make a resolution, but
i can't wrap my head around how to formulate the problem in prolog.

I have

```
KB = { P v Q, Q => (R ^ S), (P v R) => U }
```

that i put in CNF as:

```
KB = { P v Q, not(Q) v R, not(Q) v S, not(P) v U, not(R) v U }
```

and i'd like to prove that KB entails U `( KB |= U )`.

I can prove in manually by refutation but i'd like to know how this can be done using prolog ?

Thx

Comment: You do not have a set of Horn clauses, since Horn clauses contain at most one unnegated literal. (P v Q) violates that.

Comment: so its not possible to express that problem in prolog ? As for the proof, it stands by refutation

Comment: Prolog is not a universal theorem prover. It is restricted to Horn clauses.

Comment: But isn't "p v q" a horn clause ? It could be expressed as p;q ?

Comment: "A Horn clause is a clause (a disjunction of literals) with at most one positive, i.e. unnegated, literal." see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause.

Comment: Careful with ';'! It is a inbuilt [control] predicate, thus you cannot use it in the head of rules / in facts, because that would mean daring to redefine it :-)

Comment: Handling the "or" in the head of a rule is of the domain of "disjunctive databases". Good for expressing uncertainty because you know that one of P and Q are true, but you don't know which one (that's actually a classical logic stance in intuitionistic logic you are also required to indicate which of those is true). See: [Disjunctive Logic Programming: A Survey and Assessment (2002)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.8.9132). ASP solvers can deal with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: it is impossible.

> not(Q) v R, not(Q) v S, not(P) v U, not(R) v U

can be expressed by `r:-q.`, `s:-q.`, `u:-p.` and `u:-r.`.

Questioning `? u.` amounts to asking for a proof by refutation.

However,

> P v Q

**cannot** be expressed as a fact/rule in a prolog program. Prolog is restricted to Horn clauses, i.e. disjunctions of literals that contain at most one positive literal.